# visualization of CMIP6 data in python

Tags: python, netcdf, netcdf4

I am trying to plot a figure for latitudes and level over time for an .nc file from the CMIP6 dataset. But it is not working, tried to extract vector from the data but they do not have the same shape. Also tried to plot them using xarray but it gives an empty figure. I do not understand where the mistake is.

[Code part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgDCu.png)

[code part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy0D4.png)

Comment: Welcome! Please, consider this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: Have you checked if there is any data in `dsetloc` after selecting your lon lat?